# Vertices inside the donut

Tags: vertices

[image: Image with Vertices]

There is a depression on my icing and the vertices seem to be deeply embedded into it, and I am unable to view them and properly move them.

Also, the center of the torus, has no vertices at all. Please help. Thank you.

[image: Center of Torus]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=lykJ2gDy" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/lykJ2gDy/)

Answer (score 0):

You have somehow created some inner faces, go in Edit mode and *Select > Select All by Trait > Interior Faces* then <kbd>X</kbd> > *Delete Faces* and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals:

[image]

You'll still have a bad bump but you can select the bad part and do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> > *Smooth Vertices* and tweak the parameters in the *Operator Box*:

[image]

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much. That solved it.